# WebSphere Docker OAuth

Tags: oauth, docker, websphere, websphere-liberty

I need to implement OAuth against an IBM WebSphere server. For that purpose I built a docker environment https://github.com/hhoechtl/websphere-oauth according to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1305_odonnell2/1305_odonnell2.html

But if I try to get a token

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept-Charset: UTF-8" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=LibertyRocks&client_secret=AndMakesConfigurationEasy&username=admin&password=admin' "https://192.168.99.100:9443/oauth2/endpoint/DemoProvider/token"
```

I get the error

```
{
  "error_description": "CWWKS1406E: The token request had an invalid client credential. The request URI was /oauth2/endpoint/DemoProvider/token.",
  "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

But according to my server.xml that should be correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next day it just worked, no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to turn on and provide the server trace for that invocation? The message indicates that either credentials weren't found in the request, or credentials were found but were invalid for that client. It would be useful to know which is the case here.

You can enable trace by adding this snippet to your server.xml:

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=info=enabled:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all=enabled:com.ibm.oauth.*=all=enabled" />
```